# How to copy a text file onto pyperclip which has blank lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, copy-paste, pyperclip

I am using python 3.6.2 on Windows 10. I made this program to read text from a .txt file and then copy that to the clipboard. Code:

```
import pyperclip
text=(open("trackers.txt")).read()
print(text)
pyperclip.copy(text)
spam = pyperclip.paste()
print(spam)
```

The "trackers.txt" file is like this:

```
something something

something something

something something

something something
```

except it has MANY more line (100+).
Whenever I run the program and paste anywhere else, the text is there but all the spaces have been removed. However when i copy paste from the text file onto the same space it works.
Is there some setting which is stripping the whitespace??

Comment: There is nothing in the [source code](https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip/blob/master/pyperclip/__init__.py) that strips whitespace; perhaps this is a limitation of the windows clipboard?

Comment: But when i copy directly from the .txt file and paste it it keeps all formatting. It only removes spacing in the python version.